# Setting a timeout on a DLL usage

Tags: c#, windows, exception, dll, timeout

I am writing a DLL in C# and I need, (not want), to limit the usage of the DLL within a specific time.

I want it to stop working after N hours from the start of the usage, while notifying the user.
And if the DLL is not used for M hours, also stop the usage (as a sort of keep alive).

Usage being calling one of the functions of the DLL.

Using exceptions always collide with the availability of the DLL (I can't keep it in blocking).

I would very appreciate any help I can get, I am not very experienced using C#.

Any solution in any language will be great, obviously I am running on a windows computer but its components (service pack etc.) can be easily modified, if any modification is needed.

Your help is very much appreciated, thank you.

EDIT

I think I wasn't clear.
What I need is notifying the user of the end of the usage of the functions in the DLL, so he could initialize those functions again if he wants.
The DLL is not unloaded.
And I don't want to interfere with the main program process, the one using the DLL functions.

Comment: did you try something so far?

Comment: There are commercial products that do this.

Comment: afaik you can load dll into another assembly and afair you can load/unload whole assemblies, if that is what you need.

Comment: How do you plan against setting back the pc time and/or uninstalling and reinstalling the software? The only way to even have a remote (no pun) chance of not being cheated on that i can think of is to have the main part of the application as a web service where you can allow/deny access independent of any user and their hardware. - Or do you just want to limit the continuous running time?

Comment: @Corak The "or" part is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a timer:

```
System.Threading.Timer t = new System.Threading.Timer(End, null, N * 60 * 1000, Timeout.Infinite);

  private static void End(object state)
  {
     // Tell the user and end the program
  }
```

for not used use another timer:

```
System.Threading.Timer t2 = new System.Threading.Timer(End, null, M * 60 * 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

now i don't know what "used" mean for you, but in any function that is considered a "use" do:

```
 t2.Change(M * 60 * 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

to end the program you can use:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

keep in mind, that if you have more then one thread you'll might get a zombie, so make sure that all other threads other then the main thread are Background or that you abort them or single them to close.

Now i understand that you only want to notify the user...
so what i suggest is using:

```
MessageBox.Show(this, "what message you want to give the user");
```

Comment: I thought of a timer,my problem is "ending the program"part

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be really annoying, but exiting the entire process will not provide an interface of notifying  the user,it will close his program too. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TomF you're not annoying and i'm here to help :) i've edited the answer again

Comment: Notifying the user with a message box will not allow me to terminate the DLL functionality, as an uninitialization,and also that kind of a notification could not be parsed through code,my problem is that using a timer I have to operate on timeout with a different context then the main process

Comment: @TomF i begin to understand what you need slowly. might be because i haven't had my coffee yet. you want, at the timeout event, to signal your program, that it need to stop what it's doing, am i right?

Comment: Yes,I think I will just signal a static flag on timeout and raise the exception on every following call to one of the DLL functions, which is a lot less modular then I want it to be but deadlines and stuff. If you still can think of a general solution I will be really happy to use it. Thanks

Comment: @TomF you can have an event that will be raised when the timeout passed, and have every thread or operation register to that event. that will be much better, and you don't have to throw exception, other then that it's all good

Comment: That is what i ended up doing, sending a list of functions to a module wrapping the timer to be invoked on timeout.
Then on any access to the functions provided by the DLL a static flag is checked (risen by a function sent to the timer module), and if the flag is signaled then an exception is raised.
Still this can keep the user at a state of not knowing that the usage had expired for a long time, but it still solves my problem.
Thanks for your help.